# Remove url segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using the codeigniter Tank_auth library and I want to remove the "auth' part from all the urls.

```
http://mysite.dev/auth/login
```

to

```
http://mysite.dev/login
```

Comment: Codeigniter have routing - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html check it. There you can set login to equals to auth/login

Comment: I know but the library has it's own links and redirects set with the "auth" in front and its a pain to try and change them all. i just want a rewrite rule so it can be done automatically.

Comment: If your script links point to auth/login then you must change them.
And if you use @complex857 route it will work fine..

Comment: @FlorianShena, tjat alone only would work the other way around, redirecting from `/login` to end up on `/auth/login`

Comment: @FlorianShena by the way this Tank_auth is last updated 2 years ago.. Be sure that its up to date for current CI version before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [routes configuration](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html), add something similar to this to `application/config/routes.php`:

```
$route['login'] = 'auth/login';
```

Once you got this set up, you can make the webserver to redirect users from the old url like this:

```
RewriteRule ^auth/login http://%{SERVER_NAME}/login [L,R=302]
```

This one will redirect old url requests to the newly handled `/login`, you might want to handle `https://` or subdirectories in later part of the rule.

The whole setup seems a little hackish, changing the generated urls seem to be a better idea.

Comment: @FlorianShena, sorry, i think i missed the point at first. This should be working now (seem to be ok in my test environment)